# Having this error with RESTORE HEADERONLY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 43
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.TESLA_SERVER\MSSQL\Backup\backup_emp.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
```

I haven't moved backup file to any other location.

Comment: Is the file located on the SQL Server machine (as opposed to your local client PC)? Does the SQL Server service account have permissions on the file?

Comment: @charlieface The backup file (backup_emp.bak) is located in exact path mentioned above and file is in local client PC.

Comment: Well that isn't going to work, it needs to be on the server, or at least accessible to it (maybe a network share)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the full reasoning/etc behind this, but often SQL Server (especially restores) seem to not have permissions to read many areas. Try moving the file to somewhere easily accessible by everyone (I use Users\Public\Documents) and try to do the restore from there. If it works, you can then decide on next steps (adjusting permissions, making a dedicated backup/restore folder, etc).

Comment: Makes sense, thank you both of you guys